# Extract date field from a sentence using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, patindex

I am trying to extract the date from a sentence like the below in SQL Server:

> CC - Date of Pay - 7/26/2019;

Ideally, I would like to extract the date into its own column called DateofPay

Comment: is it always after `Date of Pay` ?

Comment: @Squirrel Yes it is.

Comment: then you can do it easily using string parsing function like `substring()` , `patindex()` etc

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code bellow :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(RIGHT(`sentence`,10),1,9) as NewDate
```